# Class.forName() keeps showing error: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, json, android-intent, nullpointerexception

I want to create a variable to contain an Activity.class so that I can dynamically change the Activity to be called with intent. I want the startBtn to start the intent to the last level played Activity which I will store in json format internally in the device. However, I keep showing up error when I try to use the forName() function to call the Activity class.

Main Activity.class

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     Button startBtn, chooseLevelBtn;
     Class classVariable;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         startBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startBtn);
         chooseLevelBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.chooseLevelBtn);

         try {
             /*
              * Set class Variable so that I can dynamically change the Activity
              * to be called with intent.
              * Testing the variable with Level001Activity, but app keep crashing
              * when startBtn is pressed with stack error I post below
              */
             classVariable = Class.forName("com.ed.pieces.Level001Activity");
         } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

         startBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    classVariable);
                 startActivity(i);
             }
         });
    }
}
```

Error Stack

> > java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Class.getName()' on a null object reference
> >                 at android.content.ComponentName.(ComponentName.java:129)
> >                 at android.content.Intent.(Intent.java:4449)
> >                 at com.example.ed.pieces.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:35)
> >                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
> >                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
> >                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
> >                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
> >                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
> >                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
> >                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> >                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
> >                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

P.S I will store the last level played information in json format as a string which is such as "com.ed.pieces.Level001Activity", and when the user start the app, the class classVariable should contain the Activity class of the last played level.

All suggestions are greatly welcomed. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The stacktrace says it's comming from your `Intent` within your `onClickListener`, not the `Class.forName`. Check if `classVariable` or `getApplicationContext()` is null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your exception is coming from your `onClick()` method and its attempt to create an `Intent`, not from your `forName()` call. That is because your `forName()` call is failing for some reason.

Moreover, you do not need `forName()`. Replace:

```
try {
   /*
    * Set class Variable so that I can dynamically change the Activity
    * to be called with intent.
    * Testing the variable with Level001Activity, but app keep crashing
    * when startBtn is pressed with stack error I post below
    */
    classVariable = Class.forName("com.ed.pieces.Level001Activity");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

with:

```
classVariable = Level001Activity.class;
```

and add the appropriate `import` to pull in `Level001Activity`.

Comment: Yes I think the Intent failed because of the forName() didn't call the class correctly. Yes I know classVariable = Level001Activity.class works, but I am storing the level information in json as a string, so that I have to use the string to point out to the class to asign it to the classVariable, or what suggestion do you have ?

Comment: @Charas: "what suggestion do you have" -- first, you have the wrong value for your string that you are passing into `forName()`, if it cannot find the class for that name. Second, your approach is bad from a security standpoint, as others can modify the JSON to have you start up any activity they want.

Comment: okay then I will use switch statement when pulling out the last level played from the json string, case "level1": classVariable = Class = Level001Activity.class;break; do you think this is better ? Thx

Comment: @Charas: Yes. First, that limits attackers to only being able to choose from your select roster of activities, not any activity. Second, you can build a `Map<String, Class>` up front to use to find the `Class` for a given JSON value, without having to fuss with `forName()`.

Comment: Okay then I will try using the Map<String, Class>. Thank you for your help.